# How can I merge two lists when they have different types?

Tags: c#

```
var orderedStudents = students.OrderBy(x => x.FacultyNumber).ToList();
var orderedWorkers = workers.OrderByDescending(x => x.moneyPerHour).ToList();
```

Those are the two lists that I want to merge, but I can't figure out how since they have different types.

Comment: Why would you want to merge them? What manipulation or data extraction do you want to do on them?

Comment: Do they have a common base class?

Comment: Those are two classes with name, lastName and few more properties. I need to put them in one list and sort them by NAME.

Comment: Since the main point of contention is that they are different types, you should update the question to at least show the types of the things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either derive them from common base class and then you would use sth like

```
var humanBeings = orderedStudents.Cast<Human>().Concat(orderedWorkers.Cast<Human>()).ToList();
```

or .. cast them to common base class :) `object`

Answer (score -1):

Another option : Create a class that contains the common properties

```
class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}

var orderedStudents = students.OrderBy(x => x.FacultyNumber).Select(x => new Person { Name = x.Name, Lastname = x.Lastname});
var orderedWorkers = workers.OrderByDescending(x => x.moneyPerHour).Select(x => new Person { Name = x.Name, Lastname = x.Lastname});
var mergedList = orderedStudents.Concat(orderedWorkers).ToList();
```

Comment: Probably would be better to use base class instead of manual copying.(if possible, ofc) More OOP-ish I would say.

Comment: As with most things in software development, it depends.  If you have a base class or interface with the required properties, or you can add it then yes.  If not then this is just another option ;)

Comment: Yes, sure. Sometimes even adding a single field is a huge pain :) Not even speaking about changing model hierarchy